# Changing line width in tikz makes arrow heads ignore size specification?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am having trouble in changing arrowhead parameters in Tikz.  The `length` and `width` parameters from `arrows.meta` work as expected until I also specify a line width, then all my arrowhead specifications are ignored and the default size is used.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-{Latex[width=2mm,length=3mm]}] (0,0)--(2,0) node[right]{with no line width};
  \draw[line width=1.5mm,-{latex[width=2mm,length=3mm]}] (0,-1)--(2,-1) node[right]{with specified line width};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above code renders as follows.  Note how the same size parameters are given for both arrows, but they are ignored when the line width is changed.

[image]

How can I change the arrow size and line width at the same time?

Comment: The problem is a typo : you use in the second line `latex` (with small `l`) and not `Latex`.

Comment: @Kpym no, both Latex and latex are valid arrow types.  I suppose I should change that here just for consistency's sake but I've tried both and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @kpym Wait a sec, I tried it again and it worked with `Latex`.  I know I've tried both before, but I guess that must have been with an older iteration of my efforts where something else was wrong too.  Anyhow, if you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use in your second `\draw` command `latex` (with small `l`) which is an old arrow tip (before Ti*k*Z 3) that can't be styled as `Latex` which is part of `arrows.meta` library.

So you have just to change it to title case.